# Cant delete infinitely repeating folder in folder in folder etc

Tags: windows-7

Due to a very strange issue with Eclipse ive ended up with a folder in a folder that seems to goes on forever. So on my C drive I have

> C:\foldername\foldername\foldername\foldername\foldername etc.

When I try and delete (or shift delete) the folder I get the message:
'The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation.'

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: may be this helps: http://loudtips.in/delete-folder-in-folder-infinite-deep-structure-windows-7/

Comment: That's a pretty good comment @legendinmaking , maybe you should add it as an Answer and get some rep ;)

Comment: Have you tried `chkdsk/f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution depicting exactly your problem :

There is this simple program called **Deep-remove** which is developed in c#.NET 4.0.
http://loudtips.in/delete-folder-in-folder-infinite-deep-structure-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem should not allow to create files longer than allowed. There may be some limitations in ntfs Windows support, so boot any live Ubuntu from usb/cd/dvd and try to delete this way (using only ntfs filesystem mounted in different OS).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the Microsoft tool `robocopy.exe`.

1. Create a new empty folder, e.g. `c:\empty`
2. Then copy that empty folder onto the folder which contains the long filenames which you're trying to delete, e.g. `c:\myannoyingfolder`. Do this like so in the command prompt:

   **robocopy /MIR c:\empty c:\myannoyingfolder**