# Force delete files with a rather large name

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

I regularly use Node.js to manage dependencies for programs I write, no big deal. Today I ended up with a folder structure like this: [image]

Trying to delete any file was met with this error:

> The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file
>   system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try
>   renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation.

It was already in C:\, so it wasn't going to get much shorter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](http://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)
| [How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid “File name too long”?](http://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep-and-avoid-file-name-too-long)
| [Cant delete infinitely repeating folder in folder in folder etc](http://superuser.com/questions/590023/cant-delete-infinitely-repeating-folder-in-folder-in-folder-etc)

Comment: do you have any idea how your folder structure got this large i came across the same situation when installing grunt.

Comment: @eranotzer by using npm.

Comment: i men't did the dependencies in your packages.json where written incorrectly ?

Comment: @eranotzer Yes. Because of how npm@2 worked, every dependency nested its dependencies inside of it. This meant that dependency chains could be arbitrarily long. npm@3 is looking to adjust this behavior.

Comment: If we use **Git Path**, we can use command `rm -rf folder_delete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started typing this problem while trying a multitude of commands, including `del /F` and `rmdir /S` (as well as holding shift while deleting to try to bypass the recycle bin). I think that `rmdir /S` actually deleted all of the files so I was able to proceed with deleting the folders that were leaf nodes, then progressing up the tree a few nodes at a time. Eventually I cleaned them all up, but that was ridiculous.

Answer (score 82):

Use the Microsoft tool `robocopy.exe`.

1. Create a new empty folder, e.g. `c:\empty`
2. Then copy that empty folder onto the folder which contains the long filenames which you're trying to delete, e.g. `c:\myannoyingfolder`. Do this like so in the command prompt:

   **robocopy /MIR c:\empty c:\myannoyingfolder**

Comment: Since this is part of my workflow often enough, I figured out how to integrate it with the Windows shell. See my answer below. :)

Comment: Note: this command can take a few seconds or even minutes to finish. So, don't worry and let it do the magic :-)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I had to make sure I also killed any process (IIS) that were still holding on to one of the files.

Comment: Whenever I try to open robocopy.exe a window flashes for a second and then nothing happens. Please help

Comment: For those that are curious, MIR mirrors the source directory onto the existing directory. Since the source is empty, the destination gets clobbered.

Answer (score 30):

okay, let's say you want to delete a tree `D:\very\long\path`, you don't necessarily need to use any tools such as Robocopy.

1. Go to the root directory of the drive which contains the directory
   which you can't delete
2. Create a directory with a single letter name, eg `D:\a`
3. Navigate to inside the directory that you want to delete, in this
   case `D:\very\long\path`
4. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and Cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>)
5. Navigate to the folder you just created
6. Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>)
7. Now, move up to the root directory and delete the temp folder, in this case `D:\a`
8. Then go back and delete the original directory

Comment: This didn't work for me on the first try for me.  However after repeating this procedure a few more folder levels in I was able to get everything deleted.

Comment: Great solution, worked flawlessly. Simple and effective, thank you!

Comment: GREAT!! works like a charm!!! no other tools needed. Thanks!

Comment: This works great, and I would add a point to this, if selecting files from the path doesn't work, you can select a folder somewhere in the middle of the long path and move that folder instead, to a temp folder and then delete both in a similar way.

Answer (score 5):

You can integrate this functionality into the windows shell. My enhancement to Flo's answer was too long for a comment.

I added a `Delete` command to the Windows context menu.

[image]

The `delete.reg` file adds registry entries to associate folders with the `robodelete.bat` batch file.

**delete.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete\command]
"Extended"=""
@="\"D:\\Documents\\robodelete.bat\" \"%1\""
```

**robodelete.bat**

```
mkdir c:\empty
robocopy /MIR c:\empty %1
rmdir %1
rmdir c:\empty
```

**Note**: You may need to change the paths in both files as per your preferences.

**WARNING**: There is no way to undo this command. It does not use the recycle bin and does not ask Y/N to confirm before destroying the folder for good!

Comment: Thank you for the warning.  I need this in my workflow as well but I'd like to avoid having a nuclear button in my right click menu that lacks a Y/N confirmation.  If I get time I'll take a shot at making that adjustment and suggest an edit.

Comment: @abaldwin99, like this maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/1807318/1045881

Answer (score 5):

The SuperDelete open-source command-line tool ([GitHub](https://github.com/marceln/SuperDelete)) worked for me after other options failed (Windows 10).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use robocopy, I documented this on my personal blog for you to follow:

http://clintboessen.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/how-to-delete-files-which-exceed-255.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, CDing into the directory from a command prompt and using DEL will work.

If not, you must work your name UP the directory tree: rename the lowest level folder to a shorter name (e.g. "a"), then the next higher folder name, and so on, until the total path is short enough. By working from bottom to top, you always manipulate names, that have a shorter full path than the final files.

Answer (score 0):

- Open administrative command prompt
- `net use z: c:\path`
- `del z:\*.*`

Tweak accordingly. Z: is just an arbitrary drive letter to map the offending path to. That last delete command will erase the WHOLE directory that you've mapped - so be more specific as needed.

Comment: This is very dangerous for non-power users! There is the potential to wipe a drive if done wrong.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Definitely proceed with caution on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Nice way is to have **bootable Linux on pendrive** and delete files without problems from **live CD** os.

Answer (score -1):

I had also the Same Problem, and  i found it myself, Simply Rename the Parent Folder as less as possible. Ex. If our Folder in "**D**" Drive like **D://Folder/Undelete_Folder**. Only one thing u have to do is that rename parent Folder name as small as, u can rename it "**a**". then your location will be **D://a/Undelete_folde**r. and then delete the Parent Folder.

Comment: Not only does this not necessarily work (what if it's still larger, even with the reduction?), but I mentioned explicitly that my folder was in the root of the drive.

Answer (score -2):

If all else fails

Go the the final Directory in the string.
Cut the Files
The paste back into the 4th or 5th file in the String.
Then [Shift] + [Delete] should do the Trick.

I was skeptical to run the above in elevated command prompt as I was deleting a Test Restore File from a DPM backup.

hope this helps.

Comment: This likely won't work because they will _still_ have that long file path for the cut operation.