# Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard “Enable NTFS long paths policy” option missing

Tags: ntfs, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, filenames

A similar problem as in [Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing) occurs in *Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard*. The *Enable NTFS long paths policy* is neither in `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem` nor in `... > Filesystem > NTFS` (see screenshots). Is this option available for *Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard*?

I need this option in order to restore deleted files with too long names within a still existing subfolder. Moving this subfolder to another location i.e. shorter path does not solve the problem as the deleted files will not be restorable from that new location.

The answer for [how to delete too-long-names](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete) and similar threads are no options as I was unfortunately able to delete the files, however, I can not restore them.

[image]

Comment: `I need this option in order to restore deleted files with too long names within a still existing subfolder` no **you don't need that** because all Windows supports long paths, just append \\?\ to the path, or use a decent "file manager" with long path support like WinRAR or 7z. That option is only for removing the limit for paths without \\?\ prefix

Comment: duplicates: [How to delete a file with a path too long to be deleted](https://superuser.com/q/755298/241386), [How to delete a file in Windows with a too long filename?](https://superuser.com/q/45697/241386), [Force delete files with a rather large name](https://superuser.com/q/718223/241386), [How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid “File name too long”?](https://superuser.com/q/256105/241386)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)

Comment: None of those potential duplicates answers the author’s question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this option available for Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard?

**`Windows Server 2012 R2` does not support paths longer than 260 characters.** 
 `Windows Server 2012 R2` is based on `Windows 8.1` not `Windows 10 version 1607+`, and the option you are asking about is only a feature of `Windows 10 version 1607+`.

> I need this option in order to restore deleted files with too long names within a still existing subfolder.

**What you want is not possible with the operating system you are using.**  `Windows Server 2012 R2` does not support this option.  If you absolutely must have this option you would have to upgrade to `Windows Server 2016` or greater.